# Access to private group on MS Graph

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

When I create a private group on MS Graph, I need to wait more than 10 minutes(sometimes much much more) to be able access that group on sharepoint? Other owners and members that I added to the group can access this group almost immediately. Is there a way of doing this so that I don't need to wait that long?